# Laravel 4.2 & Mailgun: Check if mail is sent

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, mailgun

I am using Mailgun in one of my laravel 4.2 projects, everything is done perfectly and is tested thoroughly on local machine before the site went live.

This website is generating a lot of emails, like roughly 100 - 200 emails per day. All the emails are being sent automatically but I have started getting complaints that few people not getting the emails. I've asked and confirmed, emails aren't going in junk / spam folders. Just in some instances, the users are not getting the emails for some reason.

I'm using free Mailgun account, can this be a problem? Or something else? Can't figure it out.

Inside Laravel, is there any way to check whether the email is being sent or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there where any failures and try it again:

```
Mail::send('emails.users.reset', compact('user', 'code'), function($m) use ($user)
{
    $m->to($user->email)->subject('Activate Your Account');
});

if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
    $errors = 'Failed to send password reset email, please try again.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issues with Mailgun and Mandrill under a similar use scenario.

The first thing to do is check Mailgun's logs for that domain and see if there are any warnings or critical failures for the recipients in question. I have had a lot of issues with AOL accounts in particular being throttled - they often receive the email hours or sometimes days later.

Next, reach out to their support team and report the issue - provide them with a few identifiers for emails that are bounced or delayed. They will generally move you to another IP address that is less "noisy." The problem is that you're using a shared IP address and some email providers may flag your mail as spam or delay its transit because of questionable activity on that same IP address.

Unfortunately, email is tricky. A dedicated IP address may help but costs money and generally does not benefit apps that send a relatively low volume of mail. I would also suggest sending a test email to http://www.mail-tester.com/ to see how email providers may view it. Very handy tool.